# What do you guys think of making videos for the promotion of our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think that members who know how to make videos, edit them and so on, should come together and make videos to help promote this site, and upload them to our YouTube channel.

I have made a video Alhamdulillah, and I have uploaded it to our YouTube Channel.  You may watch it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcknEuhYb7E  I know it isn't of the best of quality.  Captions are also provided. Currently the video linked above has more than 77 thousand views and is counting.

Comment: I have a question before I give you some feedback, Do you want the truth ? or just to hear someone saying this video was awesome ? :-p

Comment: @Suhaib the truth of course, if it is about the video I made, I already know it isn't that good.  :)  Any way I do not want feedback, I want to know what you guys think of making videos to promote this site.

Comment: 1st remove the wallpaper at the beginning and instead of using text to explain it. Use screenshots to show the users where to click so they can read the FAQ, if you can use a video recording program that would be awesome. Also remove the captions. and increase the Quality to HD. Also there are many creative ways to display the text or teach people. here is one way:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFb0NaeRmdg

Comment: btw, I am not expert too. But I think if we can get someone who is a pro to do this then it would be awesome. Other than that I don't think we need a video. Do other websites in SE have videos to promote their websites ?

Comment: @Suhaib actually, this is only an idea, and also I have no idea how to do all that to fix the video.  We do need a pro to help out.  As for other SE sites, they each have different ideas to how they can promote themselves, so this is among one of many ideas we have to promote this site.  Some may work other may not.